# How to change action bar submenu item style of menu

Tags: android, android-menu

my action bar;

```
  <item
        android:id="@+id/userMenuItem"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/logout"
                  android:title="@string/logout"
                  android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
        </menu>
    </item>
```

and style.xml ;

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_style</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#191970</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

question is how to change logout item style like font size, color ext.

```
 <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
```

is working for menu items style but i can't change submenu style.

Comment: I cannot change submenus either. Did you solve the issue?

Comment: no i didn't.
so i gave up that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the reference of `android:listViewStyle` in order to change your submenu list layout. If you want in your Light theme the menu from the dark version of Holo you can write:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
   <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
   <item name="android:listViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView</item>
</style>
```

Of course you can assign your own style with adjusted font. This will change only the drop down menu.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Listviews change, but submenus stay the same.